# HTMLEncode a string for webMathematica

Tags: export, html, webmathematica, character-encoding

Is there a native *Mathematica* way to convert a string like `"<select></select>"` into `"&lt;select&gt;&lt;/select&gt;"` and similarly for other reserved characters in html (or another encoding that would work in a webpage)?.

I'm working in *webMathematica*, but I can't find a good way to print the literal string `"<select></select>"` into a page - it either gets converted into an node, or it gets wrapped in a `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The different HTML entities are stored in `` System`Convert`MLStringDataDump`$HTMLEntities `` on version 9 and from here, it's a simple `StringReplace`:

```
StringReplace["<select></select>", System`Convert`MLStringDataDump`$HTMLEntities]
(* "&lt;select&gt;&lt;/select&gt;" *)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the necessary definitions are not present in a fresh kernel.  We need to figure out what triggers auto-loading them.  `ExportString["asd", "HTML"]` certainly does but maybe it's more than necessary.

Comment: This is the line registering the exporter: ``ImportExport`RegisterExport[
  "HTML",
  System`Convert`HTMLDump`exportUsingHTMLSave,
  "Sources" -> {"Convert`ConvertCommon`", "Convert`MLStringData`", "Convert`HTMLConvert`"},
  "Unevaluated" -> False
]``  I'm not sure what the `"Sources"` option does exactly.

Answer (score 9):

Something like:

```
ExportString[Cell[TextData["<select></select>"],"Text"],"HTML","FullDocument" -> False]
```

produces:

```
<p class="Text">
 &lt;select&gt;&lt;/select&gt;
</p>
```

which might also be a good start.