# Encode accents for html

Tags: export, html, character-encoding

I'd like to create an HTML file from a `String`, such as `"abcdéèçàdefghijk"`. I tried different methods with no success. For example,

```
s = OpenWrite["test1.html", CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"];
WriteString[s, "abcdéèçàdefghijk"]
Close[s]
```

returns a file with

```
abcde'e`c,a`defghijk
```

I managed to achieve my goal by specifying the encoding in the html file (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` together with `s = OpenWrite["test1.html", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]`) but I am curious how this could be done from MMA encoding features.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is that you don't like in your own solution `OpenWrite["test1.html", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]` ?

Comment: @Stitch That it requires the addition of a line `<meta ...` in the html file.

Comment: Well, MMA is writing the string to the file correctly (you can open it in a text editor and see the string). The fact that it is not rendered correctly when opened by a browser means that it is not MMA, but the browser that needs the `charset` option. It does seem like a proper way of doing it.

Comment: Does this work for you? `ExportString[Cell[TextData["abcdéèçàdefghijk"],"Text"],"HTML","FullDocument"->False]` I adapted this from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42574/245). The solution uses standard HTML entities instead of unicode characters. That makes the exported code self-contained.

Comment: @Stitch The question is in substance: what encoding should I choose so that the string prints out fine in a browser. As I wrote, it is out of curiosity. Maybe that's an irrelevant browser-dependent question, I don't know. I am not saying that my solution is bad and, actually, it seems [every html file should specify a character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12406142/1555099).

Comment: @Jens Yes, exactly!! That was what I was looking for. Feel free to write an answer and if so, maybe you'd want to mention that it is recommended to specify character encoding in every html (cf my previous comment). I'm not quite sure why your solution works, btw.

Comment: @anderstood Although this may be closed as a duplicate of the question I linked to, I posted an answer to briefly address the issue of avoiding encoding problems by using HTML entities instead of unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think HTML export in *Mathematica* is based on standards that date back to way before anyone had even heard of HTML5. E.g., the `Import` docs for HTML say it understands HTML 4.01.

Fortunately, even then there was already support for accents that required only ASCII characters. These are the HTML entities `&egrave;` etc. Because they come from a time in history when no character encodings needed to be specified, they work independently of encoding.

For example, this command would create a self-contained HTML code snippet that should work in any context:

```
ExportString[
  Cell[TextData["abcdéèçàdefghijk"],"Text"],"HTML","FullDocument"->Fa‌​lse
]
```

The output is

```
<p class="Text">
 abcd&eacute;&egrave;&ccedil;&agrave;defghijk
</p>
```

This is adapted from [Chuy's answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42574/245).